# Calculator program always outputs 0 - What am I doing wrong?

Tags: c++, calculator

I'm trying to create a calculator as my first C++ program. I got it working earlier using global variables but they're not allowed in my course so I've tried taking a different approach instead.

The program I have right now compiles but when actually using the program it always outputs the answer as 0.

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

void calculate(float a, float b, char op);

int main() {

    float answer;
    float a, b;
    char op;
    char replay;
    do{
        cout<<"Choose your operation: +, -, /, *, ^, %" <<endl;
        cin>>op;
        cout<<"Input your first number:"<<endl;
        cin>>a;
        cout<<"Input your second number:"<<endl;
        cin>>b;
        calculate(a, b, op);    
        cout<<"The answer is:"<<answer<<endl;
        cout<<"Calculate again? Y = Yes, N = No"<<endl;
        cin>>replay;
    } while ((replay == 'y' || replay == 'Y')); 
    cout<<"Thanks for using the calculator, bye!"<<endl;
    return 0;   
}

void calculate(float a, float b, char op)
{
    float answer;
    switch(op)
    {
        case '-':
            answer = a - b;
            break;
        case '+':
            answer = a + b;
            break;
        case '*':
            answer = a * b;
            break;
        case '/':
            answer = a / b;
            break;
        case '^':
            answer = pow(a, b);
            break; 
        case '%':
            answer = fmod(a, b);
            break; 
        default:
            cout<<"You did something wrong!"<<endl; 
            break;
    }

}
```

Comment: [Let your compiler help you.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/18810d270594f083)

Comment: The compiler should have warned you about a few things (namely, the unused variable `answer` in `calculate`, read it's output. You should always read and try to understand the compiler's output when it tells you about errors and warnings, it usually gives good advices. If you don't understand what the compiler says, it's ok, ask about it, but read it and *try* to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common basic mistake I see in beginners.

You need to **return** your calculated value and store it. If not, you function is as good as "not doing anything". (Even though it did calculate, but you didn't store the calculated output).

Your current function header is:

```
void calculate(float a, float b, char op)
```

The void infront of the function name is referring to the function's return type. Void means `don't return anything`. But you need to return the calculated value and store it, so it cannot be void.

**Change it to**:

```
float calculate(float a, float b, char op)
```

Now, if you change it to `float`. Your calculate function can now return the calculated answer of type: float, thus you are allowed to write this statement in your calculate function now: `return answer` (where answer is a float value)

To solve your problem, you may do this:

```
int main()
{
    answer = calculate(a, b, op); //Save the answer and use it later on
}

double calculate(double a, double b, char op) //I prefer double over float
{
    //Your implementation
    return answer;  //answer of type double 
}
```

---

Certainly, as you move on deeper into C++. there are a few ways to handle this problem. Your `calculate()` function will still work even if its return type is `void`. That way, you can pass the `reference` of the answer in the function. So any changes will change the `answer` under the variable scope of the main directly.

Answer (score 2):

You don't *return* the answer from the `calculate` function. Instead you just print the (uninitialized) local variable `answer` in the `main` function, which is [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) as uninitialized (non-static) local variables have indeterminate value.

Just because you have two local variables in two functions named the same doesn't mean they are the same variable. A local variable is just that, *local* to the function it's defined in. You need to change the `calculate` function to actually return the `answer` and use that returned value in the `main` function.

Comment: That doesn't really matter as he didn't do anything with the return value of calculate anyway() - it doesn't get assigned to anything ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You have two totally *separate* `answer` variables, one in `main()` which is set to an arbitrary value, and one in `calculate()` which is set but never seen outside the function.

If you change `calculate()` to return a `float` and actually *return* `answer`:

```
float calculate(float a, float b, char op) {
    :
    return answer;
}
```

and then call it thus from `main()`:

```
answer = calculate(a, b, op);
```

then that should allow you to pass the result back.

---

And, as an aside, unless you have *massive* arrays of floating point values, you're generally better off using `double` rather than `float` - the former gives you massively increased range and precision so will be more "accurate" (in the layman's sense of the word) than the latter.

Answer (score 2):

You declare "float answer" in the main and the calculate methods.
You should declare

```
float calculate(float a, float b, char op)
```

and

```
return answer;
```

from calculate method.
In the main:

```
answer = calculate(a, b, op);
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, you don't return anything, and answer inside of calculate and inside of main are completely different. You just need to change a few lines

```
// Have a return type of float
float calculate(float a, float b, char op)

// Return the calculation. Do the same for the other cases
return a - b; 

// Assign what is returned from calculate to answer so you can output it later.
answer = calculate(a, b, op);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you declare a variable inside a function the value of that variable is *local* to that function. This means you cannot refer to it outside that function. Creating another variable with the same name elsewhere doesn't link it them together.

To get the value back from your `calculate` function, you need to return it, like this:

```
int main()
{
  // ...

  float answer = calculate(a,b,op);
  cout<<"The answer is:"<<answer<<endl;

  // ...
}

float calculate(a,b,op)
{
  float answer;

  // ...

  return answer;
}
```